# Adding water with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

There are $n$ cups of capacity $1$ each. A game proceeds in $n$ rounds. In each round, you can add water to some cups subject to the following rules.

- For each $2\le i\le n$, you cannot add more water into cup $i$ than the water that was already in cup $i-1$ in the previous round.
- You cannot add more water than the water you added into the first round.

Your score for adding to cup $i$ is the amount of water you added into this cup times $1/i$, and your score for the round is the sum over all cups you added to. Your final score is then the minimum among the scores in the $n$ rounds.

Is it possible for you to score $2/n$ or more for some $n$? Or asymptotically larger than $O(1/n)$?

Scoring $1/n$ is easy, by adding $1/n$ to the first cup $n$ times, or by adding $1$ to cup $i$ in round $i$. You may be able to score above $1/n$, for instance with $n=3$, you can add $1/2$ to the first cup (round 1), $1/4$ to each of the first and second cup (round 2), and again $1/4$ to each of the first and second cup (round 3), for a score of $3/8$.

Comment: For small $n$ (e.g. $n = 1$) it is easy to see that it's impossible to score $2/n$. Do you only care about the behavior when $n$ tends to infinity? If so, then you'd better mention that in the post.

Comment: @WhatsUp I meant whether it is possible to score $2/n$ for some $n$. This is now clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to score more than $\frac2n$ and the least $n$ for this is $10$.

The optimal configuration (according to *Mathematica*) is the following (added amount of water is shown):
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc} 
\frac{669}{940}\\ 
0 & \frac{669}{1645} \\ 
0 & \frac{223}{1645} & \frac{669}{1645}\\ 
0 & 0 & \frac{2007}{6580} & \frac{669}{1645}\\ 
0 & \frac{2227}{29610} & \frac{271}{940} & 0 & \frac{1031}{2961}\\ 
\frac{311387}{3849300} & \frac{65113}{2474550} & 0 & 0 & \frac{887923}{3464370} & \frac{1031}{2961} \\ 
0 & \frac{218021}{1539720} & 0 & \frac{86672}{192465} & 0 & \frac{12295}{102648} & 0 \\ 
\frac{155117}{1539720} & 0 & 0 & \frac{5504}{38493} & 0 & 0 & \frac{20587}{43992} & 0\\ 
0 & \frac{14871071}{69287400} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1370177}{3464370} & \frac{781931}{7698600} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \frac{821131}{7698600} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{46027}{106925} & \frac{38401}{219960} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\end{array}
$$
with the score
$$\frac{669}{3290}>\frac2{10}.
$$

The table of the highest possible scores for $n=1\dots9$ is given below.
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
\hline
1&\frac12&\frac5{12}&\frac5{14}&\frac{13}{42}&\frac{77}{276}&\frac{77}{304}&\frac{261}{1120}&\frac{669}{3080}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Nice work - is the proof of 10 being minimal an exhaustive search? And could you add the score for each round, for interest?

Comment: @Joffan I can only hope that *Mathematica* algorithm did not miss something. It has generated the optimal configuration (together with the score) for all $n\le10$.  I will add the table of the scores soon.

Comment: Somewhere around 10 seems plausible, based on getting sums of reciprocals high enough. It's good to have your demonstration that an answer is feasible anyway.

Comment: @Joffan I just have realized that you asked about the round scores for $n=10$, not about the final scores for $n<10$. So the late response: except for the first round, they all are equal.

Comment: thanks for clarifying; I could have done the work myself I guess, but I assumed that you had already done it so....